# Add ListBoxItem to ListBox in a Window's UserControl from another Window's UserControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `UserControl` called `UserControl1` that contains a `ListBox`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="myClass.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Width="400">
            <ListBox x:Name="lstBox_UserControl1"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

`UserControl1` is placed in my `Window` called `MainWindow`:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars" x:Class="myClass.MainWindow">
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:myClass"
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <UserControl x:Name="usrControl_TelegramQueue" Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have a simple view model to bind `UserControl1` to the `UserControl` in `MainWindow`:

```
    partial class UserControl1ViewModel : ViewModelBase {

        private object _currentView;
        UserControl1 UserControl1View= new UserControl1();

        public TelegramQueueViewModel() {
            CurrentView = UserControl1View;
        }

        public object CurrentView {
            get { return _currentView; }
            set {
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentView");
            }
        }
    }
```

The `ViewModelBase` class just handles the property changed event:

```
    class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, I have another `Window` called `SecondWindow` that also has a `UserControl` (called `UserControl2`) in it, similar to how `MainWindow` has `UserControl1`. `MainWindow` opens `SecondWindow` and `UserControl2` contains a `TextBox` and a `Button`. When the button of `UserControl2` is selected, I would like for the contents of its textbox to be added as a `ListBoxItem` inside of `ListBox` that is found in the main window. How can I go about doing this given the fact that both user controls are contained within separate windows?

Comment: Hmm, where do you instantiate the two viewmodels? you could simply have a reference of the second viewmodel (and visa versa) in the first viewmodel as a property and simply access it that way

Comment: Oh didn't see at first, but of course you would have to bind the listbox in the usercontrol to the respective viewmodel for this to work.

Comment: In the Window XAML files I bind the view of the usercontrols to their respective view models. I thought about adding a List property to the user control with the listbox to its view model and then access it from the second view model, however, my issue is that I don't understand how I can communicate between these two and pass the data.

Comment: A `CurrentView` property does not belong to a view model, which must not know anything about a view. That is not MVVM. Your Windows and the UserControls inside of them should bind to a common, shared view model.

Comment: as @Clemens points out there seems to be a bit of a confusion which property belongs to which class. In general it is no problem to achieve what you want to do, but the way your code looks, you would have a property called `CurrentView` in your MainWindow class and you want to bind your usercontrol to this property.

Comment: I have bounded my usercontrol to this property in my mainwindow, this only displays the usercontrol in my window, within my usercontrol is a listbox. I would like this listbox to bind to data.

Comment: This UserControl should not be created by a view model. Instead, the view model should expose data as a property. In the view (the Window), there would be a DataTemplate (with an appropriate DataType) that contains the UserControl. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).